# Spring Boot and MVC: How to set default value for @RequestBody object fields from application.properties?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am writing following code:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController
{
    @Autowired private JdbcTemplate jt;

    @RequestMapping("/getUsers")
    public ListResult getUsers(@RequestBody GetUsersArgs args)
    {
        // paging query that returns ListResult object.
        // ...
    }

    private static class GetUsersArgs
    {
        public int firstRowIndex = 0;
        public int pageSize = 500;
    }
}
```

What I want to do is, to set the default value for pageSize field of GetUsersArgs object from application.properties file of Spring Boot.

When the content of application.properties file is as follows,

```
server.port: 9000
management.port: 9001
userList.pageSize: 100
```

pageSize field must be set to 100. Otherwise, set to 500.

How can it be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't going to work that way. Spring can only replace values in managed beans, yours is constructed from request parameters. What you can do is inject a value into your controller and use that

```
public class UserController

    @Value("${userList.pageSize:500}")
    private int pageSize;
```

This value you can then use in your method to set the `pageSize` on the object.

Comment: Thank you. But then GetUserArgs class cannot be a static inner class (since an object of a static class cannot access the member variables of outer class), is this right?

Comment: Why not. Why wouldn't yo be able to call a method on `GetUserArgs` from the `getUsers` method? Simply add a `setPageSize` method on `GetUserArgs` and call when needed.